# How to make a csv in a byte[]?

Tags: java, csv

I would like to know how I should make a method that makes a csv file in a byte[].

At the moment I'm using something like this:

```
 public byte[] makeCsv(){
      StringBuffer csv= new StringBuffer();
      csv.append("columnheader1;columnheader2\r\n");
      csv.append("cell1;cell2\r\n");
      //...
      return csv.toString().getBytes();
 }
```

I know I should be using streams but I don't now which ones. **Whats the best way to do this**(without IO access)**?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without IO, your way is just fine. The following is a slight improvement.

```
  StringBuilder csv= new StringBuilder(); // Faster
  csv.append("columnheader1;columnheader2\r\n");
  csv.append("cell1;cell2\r\n");
  //...
  return csv.toString().getBytes("windows-1252"); // Windows Latin-1
```

You could use a StringWriter too.

Or write to a ByteArrayOutputStream (in-memory IO) with a PrintWriter.

Comment: Oke I've changed it. I didn't know that appending Strings was a good idea.

Comment: I feel that the most important part of this answer is the last part, where a specific character set is provided to `getBytes()`.  If you don't pin down exactly which character set should be used for the byte representation, then there are many correct return values - and your caller will be confused by all but one of them.  Whenever you're dealing with byte encodings of text (in either direction), *always make explicit what the encoding is*.

Comment: Note that this does not correctly sanitize the values. Don't use this solution as-is with untrusted user input.