# How To Unit Test OpenCSV Parsing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So, I have a method like so:

```
public static List<Metrics> buildByColumnName(InputStream is, Class<? extends Metrics> clazz) {
    List<Metrics> metrics = null;
    MappingStrategy<Metrics> ms = new HeaderColumnMappingStrategy<>();
    ms.setType(clazz);

    try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        CsvToBean<Metrics> cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Metrics>(reader).withType(clazz).withMappingStrategy(ms).build();
        metrics = new ArrayList<>(cb.parse());
        reader.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error building metrics from CSV file: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I've created a unit test with two tests to test the exception cases, but I'm not sure what I need to do/mock to test out the happy path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since this is a static method, its output is generally based on the input arguments.

All you have to do is to provide the right arguments and test if the function returns the expected value, according to input values (I suppose you did the same whith exception cases).

You may need to build `InputStream` object to simulate a CSV file and provide test data.

This can be done as follows:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("value1,value2,value3".getBytes());
```

Run the method, check if you get the right `List<Metrics>`, and that's it.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I always get tripped up on what to mock and what not to mock. You're answer along with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039468/how-to-make-a-csv-in-a-byte helped me to construct a working happy path test. Thank you!